# Does an employee have the right to pay the federal and state taxes themselves instead of having employer doing it?

Tags: united-states, taxes, payroll-taxes, form-w-2

I was wondering if a W-2 employee has the option to tell their employer that they will pay their taxes instead of having the employer do it....

Comment: You could enter like 500 exceptions (as if you have 500 children) and as a result get no taxes deducted. Then of course you are liable to pay them yourself. I doubt that this is legal though, and I am not advising you to do it. If there would be a legal option for what you want, a lot of people would do it - it means a free loan. So it is probably not possible.

Comment: It's not a free loan. It invites a huge penalty for under withholding . And for the average earner, 15-20 exemptions will do. No need for 500.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer is there a specific penalty for not having enough withheld via paycheck? The OP stated they would pay the taxes directly. If they did so via properly calculated and submitted quarterly estimated payments, would that or would that not avoid underpayment penalties?

Comment: Good point. If they actually made quarterly payments, and in the end, did not underwithhold, based on the usual rules, they might get away with this. The question would remain why one would want to do it this way.

Comment: Well, one possible reason would be if you don't trust your employer to do it or to do it correctly.

Answer (score 10):

You can file a revised W-4 with your employer claiming more allowances than you do now. More allowances means less Federal tax and (if applicable and likely with a separate form) less state tax. This doesn't affect social security and Medicare with holding, though.

That being said, US taxes are on a pay-as-you-go system. If the IRS determines that you're claiming more allowances than you're eligible for and not paying the proper taxes throughout the year, they will hit you with an underpayment penalty fee, which would likely negate the benefits of keeping that money in the first place. This is why independent contractors and self-employed people pay quarterly or estimated taxes. Depending on the employer, they may require proof of the allowances for adjustment before they accept the revised W-4.

Comment: One advantage of paycheck withholding is that it is always considered received in a timely manner, regardless of when it was received in the year. With quarterly estimated payments, you not only have to pay the right total amount, but it has to be paid in the correct quarter (or earlier I suppose).

Answer (score 4):

No. An employer is legally obliged to deduct taxes from your pay cheque and send them to the IRS. The only way round that is to either provide evidence of deductions that would reduce your tax bill to nothing, or to become self-employed.

Comment: become self employed and be liable for 15.2% greater tax before stacking deductions, great observation

Comment: Your employer has no more obligation than to calculate withholding based on the information you provide them, and remit the withheld money to the IRS in a timely manner.

Answer (score 0):

No, even businesses pay taxes quarterly.  So if you formed Nathan, LLC, or otherwise became self employed, you'd still have to file quarterly estimates and make tax payments.  This would cause taxes to be a much more high touch part of your life.

However, you should ensure that you're claiming the proper exemptions etc to avoid excessive withholding.